# How do recurrent neural networks know how to close brackets?

Tags: recurrent-neural-network

I read that an RNN given a lot of text to read can learn to generate text which matches brackets (....) {...} [...] etc.

How does the RNN "know" that it has to close a bracket? Or is this just a fluke that we're reading too much into?

Where does it store the "state" that the bracket has been opened and so needs closing? And how does it learn this?

Comment: Not a full answer but relevant: one of the simplest ways to endow a circuit with memory is to have two gates feed signal to each other: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is through the hidden unit that it passes along. The simplest RNN in this case would be a character RNN, which given a list of characters so far (including punctuation, brackets, etc.), tries to predict the next character in the sequence. After every prediction, it passes along an updated hidden unit. While the hidden unit is generally abstract nonsense, it still contains the notion that at some point the sequence outputted a "[" bracket. Since 99.99% of text that contains a "[" bracket ultimately contains a "]" bracket, this kind of prior will heavily influence the RNN. So it will generally spit out a closing bracket "]" after it determines that the length of the text after the "[" bracket is long enough. This length will likely depend on the corpus of text it was trained on.

Comment: This is good. But I don't know what it means by "notion". It seems like magic.

Comment: @zooby: If the hidden state stored the entire sequence of characters thus far, it wouldn't be mystifying that it knows that a "[" occurred before. In reality the hidden state is much lower dimensional, so it's reasonable to guess that it compresses the previously seen sequence to something much lower dimensional, but given the importance of the above prior discussion, still retains the notion of a left punctuation occurring.